# Loop animation 3 times and return to start

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code running an animation and I need to to stop and revert to a relatable event after 3 blinks.

```
 $(window).load(function(){
    $(function () {
      function run_animation($element, delay, duration) {
        $element.delay(delay).fadeOut(duration, function () {
          $('.countdown-li').html("<li class='countdown-li'><a>Price updated</a>").fadeIn();
          run_animation($element, delay, duration);
        });
      }
      run_animation($('.countdown-li').delay(3000));
    });
 });
```

Comment: So which part are you stuck on? Have you tried adding a variable to count the blinks? What does "revert to a relatable event" mean? (As an aside, you don't need a document ready handler inside a window load handler.)

Comment: It will also be good to see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with full example. Or at least your HTML code.

Comment: FYI, using "$" in front of a variable name (when using the jQuery lib) typically indicates that the variable represents a jQuery object of some kind. For example: var $myTable = $('table#mytable');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could have used the setinterval timer option found in javascript. http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jQuery timer to stop animation after a certain amount of time you want, so try this script:

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function () {

        $(function () {

            function run_animation($element, delay, duration) {



                $element.delay(delay).fadeOut(duration, function () {
                    $('.countdown-li').html("<li class='countdown-li'><a>Price updated</a>").fadeIn();
                    run_animation($element, delay, duration);
                });
            }

            run_animation($('.countdown-li').delay(3000));

            setTimeout("$('.countdown-li').stop();", 5500);

        });


    });
</script>
```